# Resolving ON DELETE CASCADE in many-to-many relation

Tags: postgresql

See: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/90160)

I am having a many-to-many relationship as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection_item (
  id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  collection_id bigint NOT NULL,
  item_id       bigint,

  UNIQUE (collection_id, item_id),

  FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES collection (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
);

INSERT INTO store (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO item (id, store_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO collection (id, store_id) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO collection_item (id, collection_id, item_id) VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 1);
```

My problem is that deleting a `store`

```
DELETE FROM store WHERE store.id = 1;
```

will give the following error:

```
ERROR: update or delete on table "store" violates foreign key constraint 
"collection_store_id_fkey" on table "collection" 
Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "collection".
```

I understand the problem but I don't know how I can resolve this issue.

If an `item` gets deleted, the relation in `collection_item` should not be removed but the `item_id` should be set to `NULL`. On the other hand, if a `collection` gets deleted, *all* related `collection_item` records should be removed as well.

How can `DELETE CASCADE` work in such a setup or do I have to model my tables differently if I need this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `ON DELETE CASCADE` where you have `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/55039)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you can add `ON DELETE` behavior to the `store_id` column of the `collection` table (and that of the `item` table). Basically you can just change the `ON UPDATE` to `ON DELETE` in both of these table definitions, since I doubt you'll be updating the `id` column for existing rows in the `store` table. You also mention the `ON DELETE` behavior for the `item_id` column of `collection_item`, if you want the column value to become `NULL` when an `item` is deleted, you can use `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS store (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item (
  id       BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_id bigint NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS collection_item (
  id            BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

  collection_id bigint NOT NULL,
  item_id       bigint NOT NULL,

  UNIQUE (collection_id, item_id),

  FOREIGN KEY (collection_id) REFERENCES collection (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES item (id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that: The relation should not be deleted if the item gets deleted. If an item gets deleted, it should actually be set to `NULL`. I have updated my question to reflect this constraint. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

On this case, you have to delete table refrences before to delete stores id.
Or to do the modifications above.

```
DELETE FROM item where store_id= 1;

DELETE FROM collection  where store_id = 1;

DELETE FROM store where id = 1;
```